# Why does my compiler seem to ignore the content of an included header?

Tags: c

My codes are

```
// ./header/abc.h
#ifndef ABC_H
# define ABC_H

typedef struct      s_conv
{
    int             test;
}                   t_conv;

#endif
```

```
// ./srcs/test.c

#include "abc.h"

static int  function(t_conv *conv)
{
    //something
}
```

I want to make a library file, so I tried to make object files from test.c.

`gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -c -I./header/ srcs/test.c`

but the compiler cannot detect my struct and gave me an error message:

`error: unknown type name ‘t_conv’; did you mean ‘u_long’?
 static int function(t_conv *conv)`

Also, I already declared some functions in the header file. But when I tried to use the function in other files, it also gave me a message like this:

`error: implicit declaration of function ‘function’`

Actually, my vscode intelliSense detects them well.
But when I used command in terminal, problems happened.

What should I do?

More details.

```
// in libft.h

...

int         ft_atoi(const char *nptr); // detected.
int         ft_isnum(char c); // cannot detected.

...
```

```
// in ft_chk_precision.c

#include "libft.h"
#include "ft_printf.h"

int         ft_chk_precision(const char *str, t_conv *conv, va_list args)
{
    int     i;
    char    *temp;
    int     ret;

    i = 0;
    ret = i;
    if (*str == '.')
    {
        i++;
        if (*(str + i) == '*')
        {
            conv->precision = va_arg(args, int);
            return (2);
        }
        while (ft_isnum(*(str + i)))
            i++;
        temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 1));
        ret = i;
        temp[i] = '\0';
        while (i-- > 1)
            temp[i - 1] = *(str + i);
        conv->precision = ft_atoi(temp);
        free(temp);
    }
    return (ret);
}
```

Error

```
srcs/ft_chk_precision.c: In function ‘ft_chk_precision’:
srcs/ft_chk_precision.c:32:10: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ft_isnum’; did you mean ‘ft_isalnum’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   while (ft_isnum(*(str + i)))
          ^~~~~~~~
          ft_isalnum
```

It detected ft_atoi() function, but cannot detected ft_isnum().
What is the problem?

Comment: What happens if you insert this line before your include guard into the header? `#error This file does get included!`

Comment: What happens if you insert this line into your code file? `#error This file does get compiled!` Insert it before the include line in one experiment and after the include line in a second (delete the line before the include for the second experiment).

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Looking at this line in the code file `#include "abc.h"` the header does seem to get included quite explicitly. I do not get your point?

Comment: @Yunnosch But the source file is not in the `header`directory.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Do you think it should be? I can see the appropriate `-I` in the commandline. What do you think?

Comment: Kyung please try `-Iheader` instead of `-I./header/`.

Comment: @Yunnosch Depends on if `./header/` is appropriate.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio In which way do you think it might be invalid?

Comment: @Yunnosch I corrected valid to appropriate. We need to know the relative paths/ directory system else we don´t know where to find the issue.

Comment: That is why I proposed experiments to first prove that OP is actually looking at and editing the right files, which actually have an influence on the error messages. @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio

Comment: @Yunnosch I tried to use #error, and find that header wasn't called. But I have some codes to call the same header, some of code detected header well but the other doesn't.

Comment: @Yunnosch I found that what is the problem which I don't understand yet. My c file was including 2 headers and changing the order of header, It works.

Comment: So what you are saying is that you can compile a code file which contains an `#include "abc.h"` without errors on "file not found", but the abc.h you are looking at is not the one which gets included? Search for other headers of that name on your file system then.

Comment: If have found a solution then please create an answer yourself. I'd be interested. Make sure that the question has enough info details to make the problem visible and that the answer has enough details to make clear how that problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a `#error "Unique string which also does some explaining"` into all involved files is a useful debugging technique to trace include problems.

In your case I proposed in comments what I understand turned out to help you discover the details of your problem:

1. What happens if you insert this line before your include guard into the header?
   `#error This file does get included!`
2. What happens if you insert this line into your code file (before the include line)?
   `#error This file does get compiled!`
3. What happens if you insert this line into your code file (after the include line)?
   `#error This file does get compiled!`
   Remove the line from experiment 2. before trying this one.

They do of course introduce errors. But they do so intentionally and in a way which will tell you something about which of the files you are looking at actually are used during compilation. That is the path to understanding.

Comment: Note, I expect my answer together with the one OP is hopefully going to create to become a really helpful pair. Either one alone is probably less impressive. Please judge the pair.

Comment: Ok. I did all of advises you gave me. and I can specify what problems are. I added a new function in the header files during development because I need it.  but a compiler cannot detect it. other functions being already in the header file do well. But only function I added cannot be detected.

Comment: Which of the intentional errors do you see? The ones from the header which contains the new prototype? The one from the code file which uses the new function?

Comment: I cannot see errors in header file. In my code I alrady uploaded to question, I tried to include two header; libft.h, ft_printf.h. If I write #include libft.h first, then ft_printf cannot be included and I write #inlcude ft_printf.h first, libft.h cannot be included.
I thought that including two header can be allowed, but It can't. Is it the problem?

Comment: If you include the line as proposed into the header and do not see an error in the header, then it is NOT the header which is used. That is the point of my proposals. Look for other headers of the same name.

Comment: Let's try a differemt experiment to find out the same thing. Please rename the header you are looking at and change the include line in your code accordingly. What happens if you try to compile?

Comment: Do your headers include something like `#ifndef HEADER_NAME \n #define HEADER_NAME` ?

Comment: If possible please make a [mre] fo all three involved files. Two headers and the code file. Make it as minimal as possible whil they still demonstrate your problem. I.e. if I  change include order I can observe myself what you describe.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. I found what is the problem. when I tested before, I made .gch files but I just think that it just is temp file. I removed them and see them working fine.

Comment: Please make an answer with the details of your situation, what caused the described misbehaviour and how exactly you solved it.